# Linux as a guest on MacOS X: VirtualBox or Parallels?

Tags: django, macos, virtualization, virtualbox, parallels

I'm going to develop mostly Django sites on a MacBook Pro and would like to use Ubuntu VMs for testing purposes.

Which product is better suited for this purpose?

Can I connect to the VM via  TCP/IP (so I can have apache running on the VM and access it from Safari on my MBP)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've successfully used both VirtualBox and VMWare Fusion for this. On both systems, you can set the guest up so that it has its own IP address, and connect to it via HTTP, SSH and even native file sharing, so you can mount the guest's drive as a network drive from the Mac, and vice versa. This makes it possible to do the editing on the Mac in eg Textmate, but run the server on the VM.

Comment: Well i do it the other way round because i couldn't find any useable editors for Mac i have to run VMWare Fusion with Windows XP which only hosts one editor.

Comment: What's your favorite editor? Maybe there's something similar on the Mac. I'm currently using Fraise, which is pretty decent.

Answer (score 3):

It should be possible using [VMWARE FUSION](http://www.vmware.com). It has a good network management, and you should be able to access easily your vm via network.

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell you about my experiences with a Core2Quad Q6600 on VMWare Fusion 3.0. I have three boot partitions on this system (ahem yes it is a hackintosh running with the E-Fix USB).

So i can do performance measurements. I use it for sometimes very large compiler sessions. And the amazing fact was that Linux as a Guest runs without any measureable time difference on virtualised and native Linux. Windows7 on the other hand only runs with 40% on my machine and GUI is allmost non useable while the GNOME Desktop from latest Ubuntu still works fine.

Check this out. Virtual Box is free so there is nothing to loose.